# Unable to modify variable outside of the method

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a bot for a sudoku game. It seem to work, but there's a small problem the solved grid is only printed inside the method. When I run it, the print(game.board) print the unsolved one.

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np


class Game:

    def solve(self):
        def possible(y,x,n):
            for i in range(9):
                if self.board[y][i] == n:
                    return(False)

            for i in range(9):
                if self.board[i][x] == n:
                    return(False)

            gridx = (x // 3) * 3
            gridy = (y // 3) * 3

            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if self.board[gridy + i][gridx + j] == n:
                        return(False)

            return(True)

        def solving():
            for y in range(9):
                for x in range(9):
                    if self.board[y][x] == 0:
                        for n in range(1,10):
                            if possible(y,x,n):

                                self.board[y][x] = n
                                solving()
                                self.board[y][x] = 0
                        return
            print(np.matrix(self.board))
        solving()  


game = Game()
game.board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]
game.solve()
print(game.board)
```

Comment: PS:I copied most of it of a computerphile video

Comment: Why use nested functions for this? By the way, using `numpy.matrix()` is discouraged, and certainly unnecessary here.

Comment: Im still a begginer and the nested functions seemed like a more organized way to do it since this is only one part of a bigger script. The numpy.matrix() is only there to visualise the grid better.

Comment: _Im still a begginer and the nested functions seemed like a more organized way to do it since this is only one part of a bigger script._ You could still have `solve()` function without nesting them, it should be much more straightforward. _The numpy.matrix() is only there to visualise the grid better._ If you don't want to write something yourself, I would suggest taking a look at the `pprint` library.

Comment: agree with @AMC The function nesting is unusual and something I wouldn't do.

Comment: I think the 5-deeply nested loops are a more serious offender here. Encapsulating the recursive method is nice; better than languages that don't allow nesting: you need to append `solveHelper` or similar in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is calling recursively solving() however, it unsets the tried out numbers afterwards.

What you had to do is abort as soon as you find a solution.

Just change solving, such, that it stops when a solution is found:

```
        def solving():
            for y in range(9):
                for x in range(9):
                    if self.board[y][x] == 0:
                        for n in range(1,10):
                            if possible(y,x,n):

                                self.board[y][x] = n
                                solved = solving()
                                if solved:
                                    return True
                                self.board[y][x] = 0
                        return False
            return True

        solving()
```

**Bonus:**

Here a flattened out version (without function nesting) of your solver:
I also added an `__init__` function, so that the board is passed to the class.

```
import numpy as np


class Game:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board

    def possible(self, y, x, n):

        for i in range(9):
            if self.board[y][i] == n:
                return False

        for i in range(9):
            if self.board[i][x] == n:
                return False

        gridx = (x // 3) * 3
        gridy = (y // 3) * 3

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.board[gridy + i][gridx + j] == n:
                    return False

        return True

    def solving(self):
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if self.board[y][x] == 0:
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if self.possible(y,x,n):

                            self.board[y][x] = n
                            solved = self.solving()
                            if solved:
                                return True
                            self.board[y][x] = 0
                    return False
        return True

    def solve(self):
        self.solving()
        return self.board


board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]

game = Game(board)

print(np.matrix(game.board))
game.solve()
print(np.matrix(game.board))
```

Comment: please note, that this code just finds one solution and aborts.

If you want to see multiple solutions (in case they exist, because the sudoku grid was underspecified), then the code had to be changed slightly.

Comment: Thanck you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, once a solution is found, the backtracking still sets each cell to zero and when the `solve` call returns, you're left with your original board.

This design is quite awkward, though. Typically, you'd not reach into a class and set a `self` property from outside:

```
game.board = [...]
```

This breaks encapsulation. The `Game` class' logic will fail if the caller doesn't do this properly. Better to pass a parameter into the initializer or into the `solve` function. Since solving sudoku is stateless and is done here with just a couple of functions, it feels odd to create an object.

`Game` is a vague class name. `SudokuSolver` is clearer.

Similarly, `solving` is confusingly named; method names should be commands or actions, not participles.

`return` is not a function: `return True` rather than `return(True)`.

Avoid 5-6 level nested loops and conditional blocks. Such code is difficult to reason about. Work can be saved by precomputing all of the empty positions once, then skipping all other squares.

Here's a quick rewrite with room for improvement:

```
class SudokuSolver:

    @staticmethod
    def possible_move(board, x, y, n):
        for i in range(9):
            if board[y][i] == n or board[i][x] == n:
                return False

        grid_x = x // 3 * 3
        grid_y = y // 3 * 3

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if board[grid_y+i][grid_x+j] == n:
                    return False

        return True

    @staticmethod
    def solve(board):
        empty_squares = [(x, y) for y, row in enumerate(board) 
                                for x, n in enumerate(row) if n == 0]

        def backtrack(i=0):
            if i >= len(empty_squares):
                return board

            x, y = empty_squares[i]

            for n in range(1, 10):
                if SudokuSolver.possible_move(board, x, y, n):
                    board[y][x] = n

                    if soln := backtrack(i + 1):
                        return soln

                    board[y][x] = 0

        return backtrack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    board = [
        [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
        [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
        [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
        [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
        [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
        [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
        [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
        [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
        [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
    ]

    if soln := SudokuSolver.solve(board):
        print("\n".join(",".join(map(str, x)) for x in soln))
    else:
        print("unsolvable board")
```

Comment: Suggestion to **not** use `if res := backtrack(i + 1):`  This works only from python3.8 on and might confuse anybody who doesn't know this.

Comment: They should upgrade--no reason to live in the past and this is sort of a perfect use-case for the whisker assignment, so I can't resist. Thanks for the note though!

Comment: Good answer. Going much further than what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks, yours too. Sometimes I feel weird going into code review mode since it doesn't precisely answer the question, or answers it a bit indirectly along with a lot of other stuff.